# Clone and build Scalala with Eclipse/IntelliJ

Tags: scala, sbt, scalala

I am trying to import Scalala into Eclipse.
I had tried using the sbt-eclipse plugin by adding the lines

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0-M2")
```

to my plugins.sbt 
and I ran `./sbt update` from the root of the Scalala dir which is cloned from github,
I am getting the below error

==================================================

```
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.0.0-M2 (sbtVersion=0.11.0, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/home/tutysra/Scalala/project/plugins/}default-ffe360/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.0.0-M2: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
```

==================================================

Had anyone successfully built Scalala's source with Eclipse and can share the steps they followed?

I can also give IntelliJ a try if that is the preferred method and used by many devs.
If there are some tweaking necessary for running on IntelliJ please provide them as well.

Comment: I have sbt version 0.11.2 and the `addSbtPlugin` under `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt`. May be you can try to move the plugin reference under your home dir and upgrade to 0.11.2 if you aren't already running it?

Comment: I am using the SBT version that came with the package when I cloned it from github. I will install 0.11.2 and give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbteclipse requires sbt 0.11.2.  I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/pull/40/files) with the necessary changes to upgrade Scalala to sbt 0.11.2.  Meanwhile, you can make the same changes locally.

You'll still need to add sbteclipse to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0-M2")
```

*EDIT: The changes have been merged, and Scalala now uses sbt 0.11.2.  Grab the latest Scalala, add the config line above, and you should be good to go.*

Comment: Thanks James, I pulled in the latest changes and it worked like a charm.